# find number of 1s in a 0-1 array with all 1s “on the left”?

Tags: algorithm, math, binary-search

An array consists N many 1's and 0's, all 1's come before any 0's. Find no of 1's in the array. It is clear that with binary search it is O(log N). Is there an algorithm do this in O(log(number of 1's)) time?

Comment: Linear search would be `O(number of 1s + 1)`.

Comment: sorry about the typo it should be O(log(number of 1's))...

Comment: And Aasmund Eldhuset's answer says how to do it.

Answer (score 7):

You can actually do it in `O(lg m)` time, where `m` is the number of 1s. I won't give the entire algorithm since this looks like homework, but here's a hint: try to "reverse" a binary search so that it expands the search area rather than contracting it.

Comment: are you sure that it will be O(lg m) ?

Comment: I think @SergeyS is right: you'd have to contract the search once you hit the zeros, no?

Comment: @angelatlarge: Yes, but after `lg m` expansions, you'll be at most `m` positions to the right of the rightmost 1, so you'll only need `lg m` steps to contract back again.

Comment: Ah, yes, you are right, so it is 2lg(m) in the worst case.  Thanks.

Comment: ok i get the @Aasmund Eldhuset's point, i parse the array with 2^i steps and once hit the 0 do binarysearch at the last step. but what if i exceed the size of array before touching any 0?

Comment: ok then of course call binarysearch(A,2^(i-1),A.length,1) which is clearly O(log m).

Comment: @user1497750: Correct. In that case, you will end up doing a binary search on the last half of the array, but this will only happen when `m >= n / 2`, and then `O(lg m) = O(lg n)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you just iterate over this array, you count all 1's and finally find 0 you made N+1 steps so it's O(n+1) algorith in my opinion.

Comment: O(n+1) = O(n). There's no asymptotic difference between the functions n and n+1.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OneZero
{

    public static int binary_search (byte[] array, int start, int end, int value)
    {

        if (end <= start) return -1;

        if (Math.floor((start+end)/2) == value) return Math.floor((start+end)/2);

        return binary_search (array, start, Math.floor((start+end)/2)-1, value);

    }

    public static int nbOfOnes (byte[] array, int value)
    {

        return (binary_search(array, 0, array.length,value)+1);

    }

    public static void main ()
    {

        byte[] arr = { 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };

        System.out.println(" number of 1s is: "+nbOfOnes(arr,1));

    }

}
```

Comment: you forget passing the last argument(value) of binary_search function in the body of nbOfOnes function... or am i miss smt...